# Full disk encryption with-preseed?

Tags: encryption, encrypted-partition, preseed

Ubuntu 8.04 and later provide encryption using LUKS and eCryptfs.

The question is how to configure preseed to do it automatically? There is an option in preseed to encrypt user's *home*, but no option for full disk encryption:

```
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you could do luks automatically, how are you expecting to provide the initial password?  You either would need to have it as enter it, or put it ino your preseed file, effectively making the FDE pointless unless you immemorially reset the password after the install is complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it seem i have to solve my problem on my own,but i put notes to guide others.
the error caused on:

```
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
```

to prevent such error first try 
    d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
and solve errors, a sample is:

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm_span boolean true
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device  boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string system
#d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition \
#  select Guided - use entire disk and set up LVM
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              40 300 300 ext3                                 \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      $bootable{ }                            \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              2000 10000 1000000000 ext3                      \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              8000 8000 200% linux-swap                       \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .

d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
```

**after you got answar of lvm method you can change method to crypto**